# Finding occurences of specific string of length L inside a txt file

Tags: c++, string

Suppose I have a hexadecimal string `y` of length N of the form `y{N}y{N-1}...y{1}`.
Then given another hexadecimal string `x` of length L (L less than N), I want to check how many times (if at all) this string appears inside `y`... say like `y{N}...x{L}x{L-1}...x{1}...y{j}..x{L}x{L-1}...x{1}....y{1}`.
Which is the most efficient way to do this in C++ ?...I need a really efficient implementation as I would like to run this for a large database

Comment: It's so unclear... Could you post real-life example?

Comment: Check out [`strstr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strstr.html) or [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find). Call in a loop.

Comment: I want to compute how many times the hexadecimal say 1111 appears inside a "larger" hex (e.g if the number is 8366461111 then this appears once , if 54641111456411114342 then it appears twice)..I hope I m clearer now

Comment: What is in case of '1111111'? Do you have three matching strings then?

Answer (score 1):

Your request is a simple [string search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm). 
There are many algorithms to do that. 
Most of them will give you a good answer in O(L+N) with preprocessing.

You can also use a [suffix tree](http://marknelson.us/1996/08/01/suffix-trees/) which will provide a faster answer in O(L + Z), where Z is the number of occurrences of x in y . 
A suffix tree take a lot of memory space (O(N²)) though , might not be the ideal choice here.

Answer (score 1):

"Hexadecimal" doesn't mean a thing here. C++ is a computer language, and works on bits. "Hexadecimal" is just a convenient way to group 4 bits together for human consumption.

Similarly, C++ doesn't index strings like `y{N}y{N-1}...y{1}`. It indexes them as `y[0],y[1],y[N-1]`. (There's no `y[N]`.)

Under normal circumstances, `std::string::find` is going to be faster than your disk, which means it's fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

> Which is the most efficient way to do this in C++ ?

Try [`std::search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) across an [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) of your input file, like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main () {
  // std::ifstream input("input.txt");
  std::istream& input(std::cin);
  std::string search_for("1234");

  std::istream_iterator<char> last;
  std::istream_iterator<char> it(input);
  int count(0);

  while((it = std::search(it, last, search_for.begin(), search_for.end())) != last) {
    count++;
  }

  std::cout << count << "\n";

}
```

If that isn't fast enough, you might try [`std::istreambuf_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator).

If *that* isn't fast enough, you might try memory-mapping the file and using the initial and final pointers as your iterators.